# GitHub Issues Rest API returns 404

Tags: github, postman, github-api-v3

I am trying to access the `issues` assigned to a user (me, in this case) using GitHub's Rest API: [GitHub Issues API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/issues#list-issues-assigned-to-the-authenticated-user)

I am just using Postman.

**What I have done:**

URL: `https://api.github.com/issues`

Method: `GET`

Headers: `Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json` & `Authorization: token {my_token}`

**The above returns:**

```
{
    "message": "Not Found",
    "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/issues#list-issues-assigned-to-the-authenticated-user"
}
```

I know the token works because the API works fine if I try to fetch the user information using `/user` or list a repository's issues using `/repos/{owner}/{repo}/issues`. I created a few issues in a repo so I know it's not empty.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your personal access token does not have the required [OAuth scopes](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-oauth-apps/scopes-for-oauth-apps) to access the information provided on the `/issues` endpoint. Somehow GitHub requires at least the `public_repo` scope to get issues in *public repositories* meeting your criteria (depending on request parameters) instead of the 404 status code.

When your token has the `public_repo` scope, either you will receive the issues or an empty array (`[]`). To access issues in *private repositories*, you need the (full) `repo` scope.

Comment: I added the scope `public_repo` to my authorize request, and it started working. Thanks!